# Prop `data-swiper-slide-index` did not match. Server: "0" Client: "3" nextJs and swiper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

```js
    const breakpoints ={
        0: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        576: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        1199: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
        },
    }
```

```js
    <Swiper
        modules={[Navigation]}
        spaceBetween={30}
        slidesPerView={4}
        loop={true}
        navigation={{
            nextEl: sliderNextEl.current,
            prevEl: sliderPrevEl.current,
        }}
        breakpoints={breakpoints}
        className="sg-portfolio-active swiper-container"
    >
        <SwiperSlide>Hello 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Hello 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Hello 3</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```

This is my code to apply swiper slider. Everything works fine in desktop mode (>= 1199px). But when I switch to mobile view and reload, next js throws this error:

```
Prop `data-swiper-slide-index` did not match. Server: "0" Client: "3"

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

If I comment out the `breakpoints={breakpoints}` part from swiper slider then everything works fine. I think there is a problem with swiper slider.
I also tried to use `state` to store the `breakpoints` then pass it to the `swiper`. But it didn't work.

**Is there any way to fix it?**

```bash
swiper: ^8.4.5
NextJs: 13.1.1
ReactJs: 18.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update the swiper. swiper@9.0.0 has fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).